# Can't put margin on main because fixed header and blurb moves

Tags: html, css, css-position, centering

In my code, the header and blurb is fixed, so is the footer. I'm trying to have the main content (in main) be under the fixed header and blurb but everytime I try to add a margin to it, everything adheres to that margin.

So I made the position absolute with a margin and that work but now I can no longer center the content on the page.

This is the codepen page: https://codepen.io/defaydesigns/pen/ejxOBg

HTML

```
<header class="header"></header>
<div class="blurb"></div>
<main id="main" class="g1200">
<div class="ex1 g300"></div>
<div class="ex2 g900"></div>
</main>
<footer id="footer"></footer>
```

CSS

```
body {
margin: 0 auto;
color: #823300;
background-color:#fcf0de;
}
header {
background-color: #f36d21;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
position: fixed;
}
.blurb {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: #fff;
margin: 100px 0 0 0;
position: fixed;
}
main {
width: 1200px;
height: 1500px;
margin: 150px auto;
position: absolute;
z-index: -3
}
.ex1 {
background-color: black;
height: 100%;
}
.ex2 {
background-color: red;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Positioning is the **worst** way to layout pages. There are much more flexible options available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is going to fully answer the question but hopefully it will get you on the right path.  Using absolute to do your positioning is dangerous, you should look at something called [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).  I've attached a [codepen](https://codepen.io/kriddy800/pen/BPMyzr?editors=1100) showing what I think your going for.  If not it does show how you can still center and overflow items without using absolute positioning.  Below is the code from the codepen.

HTML:

```
<header class="header">
    <label>Header</label>
  </header>
  <div class="blurb">
    <label>Blurb</label>
  </div>
  <main id="main" class="g1200">
    <div class="ex1 g300">
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ex2 g900">
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer id="footer">
    <label>Footer</label>
  </footer>
```

SCSS:

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 0;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    .header {
      background-color: #f36d21;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
    }

    .blurb {
      background-color: blue;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
    }

    main {
      background-color: green;
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      margin: 25px;

      .ex1,
      .ex2 {
        overflow-y: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

        .filler {
          background-color: cyan;
          width: 50px;
          height: 25px;
          margin: 10px 0;
          flex-shrink: 0;
        }
      }

      .ex1 {
        background-color: black;
        width: 290px;

        .filler {
          align-self: flex-start;
          &:nth-child(even) {
            align-self: flex-end;
          }
        }
      }

      .ex2 {
        background-color: red;
        flex: 1;
        margin-left: 25px;

        .filler {
          align-self: center;
        }
      }
    }

    footer {
      background-color: #f36d21;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am familiar with flexbox but I try to avoid it because I can never get it to look and behave the way I want it to. Which, admittedly, is probably because I lack understanding somewhere.

I saw your example and it's close but I want <main> to be a set width, 1200px, but I want it to be centered on the page and still be under the margin and blurb.

Comment: AHAHA! I figured it out. Set main to justify-content: center, and header, .blurb: align-items: flex-start.

That fixed it. Thank you!